# Connect a microcontroller to the internet and download data from API

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic

Let me start by saying, I am a complete newbie on microcontrollers. So please help!

I want to use a microcontroller with a stored memory of timestamps for one year. The reason being that I want to write a simple conditional which will trigger an output depending on these times of the day (e.g. today if time == X, set output = 1)

My question is, how can I get the timestamp data into the microcontroller? It is actually downloadable via an API - can I do an API call and download the information through the microcontroller, or is there another way to store the data into its memory?

Comment: "microcontroller" is not enough - it is a long way from "microcontroller" to "Internet connected *system*" (more hardware and certainly more software).  Describe your *system*.  If the question is (or becomes) "*what hardware do I need?*", then SO is not the place to ask that - you can ask about the software, but your broad question can only get broad answers, and that may not be what you need.

Comment: Have you considered using a raspberry pi?  Relatively inexpensive, you can store time stamps in a file and toggle a digital output fairly easily with a python script.  The description of the problem is pretty thin so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but it seems like it may be a good fit.

Comment: Might consider a Pi - never thought of that. I guess in this case, I would implant the logic into the Pi, and then trigger an output radio transmission to control another set of devices. Thanks semaj!

Comment: Downloading the timestamp data from an Api is a possibility but definitely doesn't sound like the way to do it if you are a newbie to micro-controllers. Honestly i would use a cheap realtime clock IC to track the time and date via SPI or I2C on the microcontroller. It will save you plenty of time, effort and money especially if your microcontroller doesn't have any form of network interface.
A RealTime Clock IC is very cheap and it will have a datasheet that will tell you basically step by step on how to get the information you need. Much easier than using an API

Answer (score 0):

A "microcontroller" is not a complete system and they are not all the same.  It could be a lowly 8-bit 8051 running bare-metal code, or it could be a 32 bit chip capable of running Linux. There is a lot of additional hardware and software between a "microcontroller" and The Internet.

From a software point of view (and that is the scope in which the question is valid on StackOverflow), you need at least a TCP/IP stack and drivers for the network interface (Ethernet most commonly).  How you store the data is entirely within your design; your system may have a filesystem, or it may just have a small amount of EEPROM, or you might store it in on-chip flash memory for example.   You have to tailor your software solution to the hardware resources available on your system (and your system is not just the microcontroller).

Given a TCP/IP stack the "API" will be whatever that stack provides - it may be a complete BSD socket API or something more lightweight.  It may or may not provide application layer protocols such as FTP, Telnet or SSH.  For this simple application a proprietary application protocol would probably suffice allowing you to work at the TCP/IP socket level.

Another thing to consider is where time comes from.  Will the system have an RTC (requiring an RTC crystal and battery), or will it get time via the Internet connection, GPS or other source?

Comment: The system is essentially meant to control a few output devices depending on a coded conditional. But the check values differ daily, so I need the controller to source daily data before running the conditional. 
And this daily data can be sourced through an API online - so yes, it will get the time via an internet connection. Say that we will be using inbuilt EEPROM. 

My problem is writing the actual code to get the data daily. How can I do that? Do I need a TCP/IP stack inside the controller? What is the software used to do this?

Comment: The protocol of the Internet is TCP/IP, so yes you necessarily need a TCP/IP stack.  There are interface modules supporting TCP/IP to serial bridging for connection of simple devices that only have serial I/O.  Some of these modules support user code and have some GPIO so may be able to support your application stand-alone.  Note that a TCP/IP stack is considerably larger and more complex that your intended application - it will be the bulk of both the code and hardware.

Comment: Okay, how can I learn to code up a TCP/IP stack? Would you kindly provide some beginner references if you know any?

Comment: I suggest that you don't write a TCP/IP stack - you use a third-party library; it is non-trivial, but there are a number of open-source, free and commercial solutions..  Your best approach will largely depend on what hardware and development tools you are using.  It is hard to advise on the scant information provided.  For PIC at least consider http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=TCPIPSTACK

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your question depends on your design requirements and constrains:

- what microcontroller do you want to use, and how much memory will it have available?
- can it connect to the internet? Is internet connection available all the time?
- how does it know what time it is?
- do timestamps change over time? E.g. once downloaded can timestamps list become obsolete?

There are many possible approaches: you can download data manually and write the to SD card, or internal memory of microcontroller (if dataset is small). Or you can program microcontroller to download data using API. Just keep in mind its memory limitations. Many units have only 1-2kB of RAM, so downloading all data at once and storing it in RAM can become a problem.

Comment: Yes, assume internet is available all the time, and that I am using a controller that can connect. The set of time stamps for the day is downloaded - so this process happens everyday (which should avoid data size issues).

Your third question about how it knows what time it is - I'm not sure. If you could share some insights as to weather this can be done with as little hardware as possible, that would be really appreciated.